# Exclude quotes inside a match

Tags: php, regex

I want to find and replace `foo='bar'` from a string - a common stylesheet link

```
<link rel='stylesheet' href='http://www.foo.com/bar/baz.min.css' type='text/css' id='23434' foo='bar' media='all'/>
```

Means: `foo` could be everywhere after `<link rel='styleshet'`, there could be a space afterwards, quotes can be single `'` or double `"`

My expression so far

```
/<link rel=[',"]stylesheet[',"].*(id=[',"].*[',"])/i
```

Obviously it ignores the quotes between the first and the last quote - I've tried a negative look-ahed but w/o success.

Comment: Please stop using regular expressions to parse HTML. Use a HTML parser instead!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use a HTML parser:

```
// this is just a snippet for testing and demonstration purposes.
// The OP works with a complete HTML document.
$html = "<link rel='stylesheet' href='foo.com/bar/baz.min.css' type='text/css' id='23434' foo='bar' media='all'/>";

$dom = new DOMDocument();
$dom->loadHTML($html);

$selector = new DOMXPath($dom);

foreach($selector->query('//link[@type="text/css"]') as $link) {
    $link->removeAttribute('id');
    $link->removeAttribute('media');
}

echo $dom->saveHTML();
```

See it working here:

Comment: How can I replace id='foo123' from my string with an HTML parser?

Comment: I don't get you? Which information are you missing?

Comment: I want to remove the id attribute with value from the link. 
`<link rel... id='foo'/>` to `<link../>` **w/o** id='foo'

Comment: Then use `$link->removeAttribute('id');`

Comment: well where comes $link then frome? Sorry, but this is actually not helpful yet. IC my question should be more clear

Comment: I don't get you. Have you tried my code? Can you address exactly what the prioblem is? I'm sure we'll find an answer quickly if you express what you want - this is best done by telling "this is input ...., this is expected output ... "

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/51293/discussion-between-lucas-and-hek2mgl)

Answer (score 1):

To answer your literal question in the title, `[^"]` is "any character except quote". But hek2mgl has the correct answer to your current problem: use HTML parser.

Answer (score 0):

if

```
foo='bar'
```

always comes after

```
id='23434'
```

you can use

```
/.+id=.+\s(.+)\s/
```